# How does the Eldritch Heritage feat function if you're already a Sorcerer?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, sorcerer, bloodline

How does the Eldritch Heritage feat function if you're already a Sorcerer?

I'm a sorcerer with Celestial bloodline.

[Eldritch Heritage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/) finishes by saying:

> You do not gain any of the other bloodline abilities.

Does that mean in general you can't gain any other bloodline abilities? Or is that specific to the bloodline chosen with this feat?

I think it's the latter but I wanted a second opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A creature with Eldritch Heritage gains bloodline abilities from other sources normally

In context, the benefit of the feat [Eldritch Heritage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/), in part, says, "You gain the first-level bloodline power for the selected bloodline. For purposes of using that power, treat your sorcerer level as equal to your character level –2, even if you have levels in sorcerer. You do not gain any of the other bloodline abilities."

While I agree that this could be clearer, it means, "You do not gain any of the other bloodline abilities due to this feat." It does *not* mean, "You do not gain any other bloodline abilities at all ever." (The key is the words *of the* between *any* and *other*. Were that *of the* missing, the feat would, indeed, prevent the creature from other bloodline abilities generally!)